# How do I run 'python -m' command in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, spacy

Some imports e.g. spacy need me to run:

`python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm`

How do I manage to make this happen from within a cell in jupyter lab?

Or can I simply put this in a requirement.txt file?

The goal is to make a notebook run without installing something extra, but the requirements file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply run these command in the cell by putting a "!" before the line of code

ex.

```
! python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

this will work.

Happy Coding!